# list of addresses for major bitcoin exchanges

Tags: exchanges

Is there a list available of the addresses for the aggregating wallets of major bitcoin exchanges? If so, where?

Comment: If I may add... I am interested in contact / support e-mail addresses of said exchanges. I would like to warn them about a scam.

Comment: Actually, this list is quite useful already:
https://cn.etherscan.com/directory/Exchanges/Crypto_Exchanges?q=&p=1

Comment: @marfi - If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use this website. https://www.walletexplorer.com/

You can filter bitcoin addresses by business organizations. You can also see updated list of transactions by each business organization. This site has exchange, pool, and other addresses.

Definitely never take information like this at face value, but it does provide some interesting insight.

Comment: Thank you @mango. How do you see the actual addresses from WalletExplorer? I see the names of the exchanges and can access the transactions that take place within their wallets (and the addresses of those they trade with) but I don't see their actual address. 
Also, would you please explain how the "balance" is arrived at within a given wallet? If you look at Poloniex, for instance:
https://www.walletexplorer.com/wallet/Poloniex.com 
the recent transactions are positive (received) but their balance is decreasing. Is this the balance of bitcoin that Poloniex holds in its wallet?

Comment: @Apod If you click on a specific business org like Poloniex, there is a "show wallet addresses" link that will produce a list of actual addresses they own. The balance is the spendable utxo at a given time. After just a quick eye test, it doesn't seem Poloniex's balance is decreasing. Keep in mind that the time delta between each transaction is very small. Tens of Bitcoin are transacted with their wallet every second or so.

Comment: Thank you @mango. Where do you find this information? My searches have not come up with any information explaining the layout of WalletExplorer.

Comment: Glad to help. Unfortunately I cannot myself find this information online - I had the website explained to me in-person at a meetup. @Apod

Answer (score 5):

Try searching for largest balances on the blockchain explorers and they sometimes have them labeled. For example: [Bitcoin Rich List](https://bitinfocharts.com/top-100-richest-bitcoin-addresses.html) shows:

- `3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r`
  wallet: Bitfinex-coldwallet 179,384 BTC
- `16ftSEQ4ctQFDtVZiUBusQUjRrGhM3JYwe`
  wallet: Binance-wallet  158,779 BTC
- `16rCmCmbuWDhPjWTrpQGaU3EPdZF7MTdUk`
  wallet: Bittrex-coldwallet  112,203 BTC
- `3Nxwenay9Z8Lc9JBiywExpnEFiLp6Afp8v`
  wallet: Bitstamp-coldwallet 101,848 BTC
- `3Cbq7aT1tY8kMxWLbitaG7yT6bPbKChq64`
  wallet: Huobi-wallet 98,042 BTC